# What is strange blade function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There is the following code in template blade:

```
{{__('services.service_4_header')}}
```

So, in path: `resources\lang\` there is languages directory: 'en' with file `services.php` with array. `(key=>value)`?

Does it mean that function `__()` gets words by key from this file?

Comment: Keep in mind that you could use dot notation to access deeper levels of your array from file. Instead `service_4_header` you can use `sevice.4.header` which coresponds with services file in lang directory, `['service']['4']['header']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__()` function fetches translations from the current locale file (or a default). It's supposed to help you with internationalization / localization.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization#retrieving-translation-strings

> You may retrieve lines from language files using the `__` helper function. The `__` method accepts the file and key of the translation string as its first argument.